# Get a vaule by key from nested hashtable

Tags: c#

I have a nested Hashtable that looks like this.

```
  Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
  Hashtable subtable = new Hashtable();
  Hashtable options = new Hashtable();

  options.Add("file","foo");
  subtable.Add("post_option",options);
  table.Add(0,subtable);

  //foreach here
```

This is what I have to work with, and I can't get any father up the chain to change what it is.  So what I need to be able to do is get "foo" by calling for the key "file" starting from the "table" hashtable.  I have tried every combo of foreach and .Keys and .Values.  I just can't seem to get it lol.  Thank you

Comment: Any reason you are not using a generic Dictionary<TKey, TValue>?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: yes sadly it's not in my control here, this is just what I get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerator of `Hashtable` works similar to enumerator of `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, but it is not generic as it is ancient API came from .NET 1 where generics do not exist. So if you want to iterate over `Hashtable` with `foreach` you need to specify the type of item. In case of `Hashtable` it is [`DictionaryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry).

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry tableEntry in table)
{
    // your logic
}
```

If you do not know the keys of the first two tables, then you need to do something like this.

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry tableEntry in table)
{
    Hashtable subtable = tableEntry.Value as Hashtable;
    if (subtable == null)
        continue;
    foreach(DictionaryEntry subtableEntry in subtable)
    {
        Hashtable options = subtableEntry.Value as Hashtable;
        if (options == null)
            continue;

        object file = options["file"];
    }
}
```

Comment: that's that ticket, and yeps right, it's an old app I have to deal with here, and why the funkiness.  Surprised any downvoted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do:

```
object foo = table[0]["post_option"]["file"];
```

Comment: That's assuming that there is only one in the "table".  That is why I need to loop over it